# Windows Installer cannot execute EXE install files

Tags: msi, windows-installer, executable

When I run the `msiexec.exe` with an `msi` file, it runs perfectly.
The problem is that many install files are not `msi`'s but `exe`'s.

My question is: How can I run an `exe` file with the `msiexec.exe` command?
If it's not possible, is there a way to convert the `exe` to `msi` properly?

Thank you very much,

Regards.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You cant run a exe with msiexec commands. You need to use supported commands for the exe you are deploying. Check out this site www.appdeploy.com/packages for info on switches for software.

Regards.

Todd

Comment: Yes, they are two different things. The exe may be a compressed package as SmallClanger pointed out with an MSI file inside. AppDeploy is a wonderful resource.

Comment: Thank you! (Even if all the apps on appdeploy are not msi's :( )

Answer (score 1):

Grab 7-zip and extract the exe file. In some cases, the exe is just a wrapper around an msi file and you might be able to install that directly.

A lot of .exe installers are built with something other than MSI, though, so you might be out of luck.